# PasswordSignInAsync hangs in .Core App

Tags: .net, f#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm building a .NET core web app in F#, and am trying to set up Identity. I have got a basic version of a Register method working, which creates a user in the database and creates the cookie:

```
[<HttpPost>]
[<AllowAnonymous>]
member this.Register([<FromBody>]model: RegisterViewModel) =
    if not (isNull model.Email) && model.Password = model.ConfirmPassword then
        let user = ApplicationUser(userName = model.Email, email = model.Email, password = model.Password)
        let result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
        if result.Succeeded then
            signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent = false) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
            true
        else
           false 
    else
        false
```

However, my Login implementation hangs:

```
[<HttpPost>]
[<AllowAnonymous>]
member this.Login([<FromBody>]model: LoginViewModel) =
    if not (isNull model.Email && isNull model.Password) then
        let result = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure = false) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
        if result.Succeeded then true else false
    else
        false
```

This is where the application hangs:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
  Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedUserName_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName]
  FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]
  WHERE [u].[NormalizedUserName] = @__normalizedUserName_0
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger?  Is it hanging inside the call to `PasswordSignInAsync`?

Comment: yep, I'm pretty sure it's hanging inside PasswordSignInAsync - I haven't been able to attach a debugger in vs code for F# though. Strangely, when signInManager.SignInAsync is called from the Register method, that works fine.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but it seems like you should be using `||` instead of `&&` in the check in `Login`.

Comment: You're right, that was wrong. It wasn't the issue causing the hang though. I've built a simple .net core app in c# on the same machine, and the login functionality works ok there. I tried using the same db with my F# app, and the problem persists, so it does seem like it's a code issue somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you just use `_.Result` instead of `_ |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously`?  There seems to be no benefit to creating F# `Async<_>` objects from your `Task<_>` in this case.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it sounds like maybe [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/789) is describing a similar issue?  Does `Login` hang when you pass in incorrect information, too?

Comment: it seems like it might be related to that issue, but I am using the default identity roles. If I try and login with an email for which there isn't a user, the method returns false (as expected).

Comment: Ah, you were correct! It was actually the same as the issue on Github. I'd added an extra constructor to the ApplicationUser class. Removing that has somehow resolved it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not actually letting this run async?

Comment: Using `Async.RunSynchronously` is the same as using `.Wait()` or `.Result`. It will block the current thread. Don't do it. Make the controller action asynchronous instead of blocking it.

Comment: See my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869267/calling-c-sharp-async-method-from-f-results-in-a-deadlock) - I am sure it's the same or similar problem. I used to use the same `|> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously` chain and started getting deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/23/async-actions-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx), the handlers can be `async` (in the C# sense) so it makes sense to rewrite your route-handler to be non-blocking, thus removing the `Async.RunSynchronously` that is likely causing the issue.

We can write the actual logic in an F# `async` workflow, because that is more idomatic, and then convert it to a `Task<_>` in order to match the expected C# signature.

```ml
[<HttpPost>]
[<AllowAnonymous>]
member this.Login([<FromBody>]model: LoginViewModel) =
  async {
    if not (isNull model.Email && isNull model.Password) 
    then
      let! result = 
        signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure = false) 
        |> Async.AwaitTask 

      return result.Succeeded
    else
      return false
  }
  |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Dead-locks can be very hard to hunt down, so when using F# `async` you should try to have only one call to `Async.RunSynchronously` in your application, usually in the "main" method.